# The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large WCF Application

Tags: wcf

My Setup:

WCF application hosted in IIS Express
Windows Form Application to test WCF App

This is WCF Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="ArxivarBridgeService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
     <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="myBasicBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="01:50:00" openTimeout="01:50:00" sendTimeout="01:50:00" receiveTimeout="01:50:00" >
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="8388608" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="false" maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  <security>
         <requestFiltering>
           <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
             <remove fileExtension="." />
             <add fileExtension="." allowed="true" />
           </fileExtensions>
         </requestFiltering>
       </security>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

</configuration>
```

This is app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IArxivarBridgeService" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
      <client>
        <endpoint address="address"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IArxivarBridgeService"
          contract="ServiceReference1.IArxivarBridgeService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IArxivarBridgeService" />
      </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

In the test application I recover a 3 MB pdf file, recalling a service method as input data, I have the byte arrey obtained from the pdf, the file name, a Dictionary and 3 strings, the method Returns the error "The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large", did I write the config wrong? Or is some parameter missing?

Comment: show me your client's address of the service endpoint located in the `appconfig`, Http or https protocol will determine what configuration is set in the server-side.

Comment: Thanks but I resolved